# Includepdf : issue with figures in addtolist

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, errors, pdfpages

I am using the package [pdfpages](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) and I have troubles using the addtolist. I tested with tables and lstlisting (it worked) but for weird reasons, it didn't work with figures :

MWE :

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
    \usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
    \usepackage{titletoc}
    \usepackage{hyperref}% Just in case....


    \providecommand{\phantomsection}{}

    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\appendixlistingname}{Appendix Listings}
    \newcommand{\listofappendixlistings}{%
      % Applying the same trick as listings does with \lstlistoflistings: Modifying \@starttoc such that it can load only .apl files
      \begingroup
      \let\@starttoc@orig\@starttoc%
      \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\appendixlistingname}
      \renewcommand{\@starttoc}[1]{%
        \@starttoc@orig{apl}%
      }%    
      \phantomsection
      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\appendixlistingname}
      \tableofcontents% Calling \tableofcontents with the `.apl` file instead of `.toc`
      \endgroup
    }

    \newcommand{\appendixFix}{%
      \setcounter{lstlisting}{0}%
      \@ifundefined{theHlstlisting}{%
        }{%
          \renewcommand{\theHlstlisting}{appendix}
        }%
      \write\@auxout{%
        \string\let\string\latex@tf@lol\string\tf@lol% Store the original `\tf@lol` file handle
        \string\let\string\tf@lol\string\tf@apl% 
      }%
    }{}{}
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}

    % Start partial lists
    \startlist[appendices]{lof}% starts appendices list of figures
    \startlist[appendices]{lot}% starts appendices list of tables

    % renaming later
    \newcommand\listfigurenameappendixes{\listfigurename}
    \newcommand\listtablenameappendixes{\listtablename}

    \appendixFix

    \begin{appendices}

        \begingroup
            \let\clearpage\relax
            % prints appendices list of figures
            \printlist[appendices]{lof}{}{
                \chapter*{\listfigurenameappendixes}
            }
            % prints appendices list of tables
            \printlist[appendices]{lot}{}{
                \chapter*{\listtablenameappendixes}
            }
            % prints appendices list of tables listings
            \listofappendixlistings
        \endgroup

    \includepdf[
        pages=1,
        pagecommand=\chapter{Analyse Bibliographique}\label{annexe:AnalyseBiblio},
        offset=0 -1cm, 
        scale=0.8
    ]{example-image-duck.pdf}

    \includepdf[
        pages=2-,
        pagecommand={},
        width=1.2\textwidth,
        % To have items into list of figures / tables / listings
        % WARNING : As explained by the doc, this option is experimental (it MAY change but I don't think so : many people used that)
        % SECOND WARNING : the page number argument is the real position from starting point !!
        addtolist={
            8, table, {Les 5 types de données de la LOM}, tab:typeLOM,
            15, table, {Éléments de base de notre norme}, tab:baseNorm,
            16, table, {Éléments d'un mot-clé de notre norme}, tab:KeyElementsNorm,
            16, table, {Quelques éléments additionnels de notre norme}, tab:ExtendedElementsNorm,
            17, lstlisting, {Exemple d'une ressource information avec notre norme}, code:exampleJson
            % Bug with figures : no idea why
            %5, figure, {Les 15 éléments de la Dublin Core}, fig:dcListElements,
            %6, figure, {Les 9 catégories d'éléments de la LOM}, fig:LOMTable,
            %7, figure, {Représentation hiérarchique de la LOM}, fig:LOMChart,
            %7, figure, {Correspondance des éléments entre la Dublin Core et la LOM}, fig:mappingDcLom,
            %9, figure, {MLR - Spécification d’un élément de données}, fig:mlr,
            %9, figure, {MLR - Exemple de spécification d’un élément de données}, fig:mlr2,
            %10, figure, {Représentation simplifiée de la MLR}, fig:mlr3,
            %11, figure, {Exemple de taxonomie pour les exercices de programmation}, fig:taxonomieEx,
            %12, figure, {Liste des sous-domaines de l'informatique selon la CC2005}, fig:AllDomainInInfo,
            %13, figure, {Exemple de hiérarchie de compétences}, fig:comptenceTree,
            %13, figure, {Catégories d'exercices informatiques}, fig:CatExoList
        }
    ]{example-image-duck.pdf}

    \end{appendices}

    % Stop partial lists
    \stoplist[appendices]{lof}% stops main list of figures
    \stoplist[appendices]{lot}% stops main list of tables

    \end{document}
```

If I uncomment all the figures (and not forgot to put a comma after lstlisting), I got this message :

[image]

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message speaks of `\ext@lstlisting` and the problem is not with figure but with listings: the package doesn't define all the commands pdfpages expects here and so it doesn't know where to write the entry.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\makeatletter    
\def\ext@lstlisting{lol} %<------------ added
\makeatother
\begin{document}

    \includepdf[
        pages=2-20,
        addtolist={
             17, lstlisting, {Exemple d'une ressource information avec notre norme}, code:exampleJson
        }
    ]{example-image-duck}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Nice try but pdfpages said "Package pdfpages Warning: There's something wrong with the entries of `addtolist'. Not all entries were processed. Check `addtolist' on input line 87." Any ideas ?

Comment: I get no warning with my example. Which version of pdfpages do you use?

Comment: Try with the full example (and add your line) : you will see it is still here.
MikTeX use the version released at 29-01-20

Comment: I can't try with your full example: it uses files I don't have.

Comment: Can you just try with a dummy file ? This  file has 20 pages so I guess any 20+ files would match (like this one : https://github.com/jy95/ghostscript-action/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.pdf ). If not, let's try by tchat

Comment: If you cannot reproduce, I have a overleaf project with this code. Let me know if I must give you access

Comment: My example use a dummy file, so yes I know how to do it. But I already once converted your code to something I can test and I won't do it again. So if I should look edit your question so that it shows something that I can simply copy & paste.

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/read/qhhpbfcpfcyk you can fetch my pdf file here

Comment: No, add the example here to your question. This here is not your personal support service - questions and answers should be usable for other people too. My code shows which dummy pdf you can use.

Comment: EDIT : I added it in the question

Comment: Sorry but who has a problem here? Why do you expect constantly that I should do the work?And no, I'm not interested in a link to some external pdf. Change your example so that it uses a dummy pdf that I already have like example-image-duck.pdf.

Comment: Replaced : last time I check, I see no rules about MWE additionnal files ^^

Comment: If I add my additional definition the code compiles without error and warning.

Comment: I updated the MWE just to be sure I don't forget a package (it seems it was the case) I find strange that figures aren't inside the table of figures of appendix whereas there is no problem with tables ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108225/discussion-between-jy95-and-ulrike-fischer).